# UILabel is not replacing previous text when view refreshed

Tags: swift, uikit

I have the following function being called in a ViewController that passes in data to build a list of transactions. Each time the page refreshes, this is called and new data is shown. All is good, except for one remaining frustrating bug: when the new data is loaded the previous `balancedOwedAmountLabel.text` still shows the previous amount.

So on each refresh, the text is written on top of the previous text each time. This results in a jumbled mess of text each time the page is refreshed. It would be expected to have the previous text removed, and replaced with the new text that I determine.

I've tried manually setting the `balancedOwedAmountLabel.text = nil` to simply remove it and then reset it each time the data is retrieved and painted, but it won't work. I've also tried removing the subview entirely via `balancedOwedAmountLabel.removeFromSuperview()` and that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Since I'm not using a Storyboard I can't connect `IBOutlets` so I'm having to resort to figuring out how to get around this problem programmatically. How do I go about solving this with the following code?

```
    private func buildTransactionTableView() {
        let stackview = UIStackView()
        stackview.axis = .vertical
        stackview.distribution = .fill
        stackview.spacing = 15
        self.view.insertSubview(stackview, belowSubview: (self.accountSummaryTableViewController?.view)!)
        
        stackview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.transactionsTableView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        stackview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        stackview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: -30).isActive = true
        
        
        // full width parent SV
        let headlineStackView = UIStackView()
        headlineStackView.axis = .horizontal
        headlineStackView.alignment = .top
        headlineStackView.distribution = .fill
        
        
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:200,height:21))
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .left
        titleLabel.textColor = .black
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.00)
        titleLabel.text = "Transaction History"

        headlineStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(headlineStackView)
        
        // SV for balance informations
        let balanceStackView = UIStackView()
        balanceStackView.axis = .horizontal
        balanceStackView.distribution = .fill
        
        headlineStackView.addArrangedSubview(balanceStackView)
        
        let balanceOwedLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        balanceOwedLabel.textAlignment = .right
        balanceOwedLabel.textColor = .black
        balanceOwedLabel.font = balanceOwedLabel.font.withSize(14.00)
        balanceOwedLabel.text = "Balance Owed"
        
        balanceStackView.addArrangedSubview(balanceOwedLabel)
        
        let balancedOwedAmountLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
        balancedOwedAmountLabel.textAlignment = .right
        balancedOwedAmountLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 33.00/255, green: 150.00/255, blue: 243.00/255, alpha: 1.00)
        balancedOwedAmountLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14.00)
        
        var amount = 0.00
        for rtp in self.userTransactions! {
            if rtp.repaymentDate == nil && rtp.rtpData.amount.value != nil {
                let value = Double((rtp.rtpData.amount.value)!)
                amount = amount + value!
            }
        }
        
        balanceStackView.addArrangedSubview(balancedOwedAmountLabel)

// This amount overwrites previous amount on screen when refreshed
// The amount is not being removed and replaced wih this new amount
        balancedOwedAmountLabel.text = " $\(String(format: "%.2f", amount))"

        let rtpTableVC = UserTransactionsTableViewController(style: .plain)
        rtpTableVC.tableView.allowsSelection = false
        rtpTableVC.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        rtpTableVC.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        rtpTableVC.rtpTransactions = self.rtpTransactions
        
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(rtpTableVC.view)
        self.userTransactionsTableViewController = rtpTableVC
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the swiftui tag for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like each time this function is called, you create a new `stackview` and add it in `self.view`. But I cannot see when you remove previous `stackview`?

One way of fixing it would be: store reference on current `stackview` and remove it before adding new one as:

```swift
var currentStackView: UIStackView? 
private func buildTransactionTableView() {
    currentStackView.removeFromSupperView()
    let stackview = UIStackView()
    currentStackView = stackview
    ...
}
```

Comment: Current implementation is not removing any previously created views. Oddly this one UILabel is causing issues yet others are fine. I'll try your solution and report back.

Comment: Most likely label is only subview with transparent background. Anyway, not removing previous (redundant) views is a bad idea.